# How to list all the managed @Component in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, inversion-of-control, autowired

I am trying to list all the managed Components in a Spring Boot application using a ListableBeanFactory interface as illustrated in [How to Get All Spring-Managed Beans?](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-show-all-beans)

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        displayAllBeans();
    }

    public static void displayAllBeans() {
        String[] allBeanNames = applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames();
        for(String beanName : allBeanNames) {
            System.out.println(beanName);
        }
    }
}
```

When running the application I get the following Exception indicating that the `applicationContext` object is `null`

```
Exception in thread "restartedMain" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at mygroup.myapp.displayAllBeans(myapp.java:18)
    at mygroup.myapp.main(myapp.java:14)
    ... 5 more
```

What am I missing? Thanks in advance

**UPDATE:**

The code from the example works as expected. There was a mistake in my code that prevented the `applicationContext` variable to be set up correctly.

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception, i.e. which line is line `18`?

Comment: @j.xavier.atero Check official example: [Spring Boot Guide](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-spring-boot/blob/master/complete/src/main/java/hello/Application.java)

Comment: @Turing85 line 18 is `String[] allBeanNames = applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames();` but `applicationContext` is `null` when that line is reached

Comment: @jpact I cheked the official example that you indicate and it works, thanks!

Comment: @j.xavier.atero glad it helps! I wrote some additional information to answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that the `ApplicationContext` instance was created by **`main`** thread, but then, for whatever reason, it was accessed by **`restartedMain`** thread.

As `applicationContext` attribute is not `synchronized`, nor `volatile`, the `restartedMain` thread accessed the stale data - thats why `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

To print out all of beans managed by Spring, you can use example from [offical sources](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-spring-boot/blob/master/complete/src/main/java/hello/Application.java).

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(ApplicationContext ctx) {
        return args -> {
            System.out.println("Let's inspect the beans provided by Spring Boot:");
            String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
            Arrays.sort(beanNames);
            for (String beanName : beanNames) {
                System.out.println(beanName);
            }

        };
    }
}
```

Comment: adding to the response ... The `restartedMain` thread is generated by devtools [SpringBoot app starts multiple times ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38635451/springboot-app-starts-multiple-times-and-disconnects-from-logstash). With devtools disabled the "only" running thread is `main`, executing the application in that scenario `applicationContext` is still `null`